# Alarms not always triggering android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

*I am developing an Android application which triggers an alarm at certain time that the user selects. But the problem is this alarm is only triggered if the user sets it to a little amount of time from now. So it's like if the app is not running the alarm won't trigger. I already acquired a lock and also set the flags to keep the screen on. Sometimes when I set it to 15 minutes from now or something like that it works and then I try again and it doesn't. I also included the broadcast receiver in the manifest. Here's my schedule alarm code:

```
public void schedule(Activity activity){
    Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivityBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", this.getId());
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1234565666, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, this.getCalendarTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

To get the calendarTime i use the following function where time is the string of the time the user entered:

```
private Calendar convertTimeStringToCalendar(){
    String[] timeArray = this.time.split(":");
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[1]);
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    int nowHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int nowMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    if (hour < nowHour  || (hour == nowHour && minute <= nowMinute)) {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return c;
}
```

And finally this is my broadcast receiver:

```
public class AlarmActivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    WakeLock.acquire(context);

    Alarm alarm = DataBaseSQL.getAlarm(intent.getLongExtra("id", 0L));
    Intent alarmActivityIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
    alarmActivityIntent.putExtra("id", alarm.getId());
    alarmActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    alarmActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
    context.startActivity(alarmActivityIntent);
}
}
```

I would appreciate any help in what it could be the reason for the alarms triggering only sometimes.

Comment: `and also set the flags to keep the screen on` so, to **kill the user's battery**?

Comment: No, it's an alarm clock so i need the screen on till the user dismisses it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is working fine for me you can use it i hope it will work for you.

this is a fetch data method in main activty

```
public void fetchdata() {       
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
              calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
              calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
              calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
              calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
              calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
              pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);
              AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
              alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }


This is broadcast receiver class



 public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        int notifyID=1;
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent i=new Intent();
            PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,i,0);
            NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notify=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Notification Triggered",System.currentTimeMillis());
            CharSequence from="Remainder";
            CharSequence message="Hurry up!!!!";
            notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, pi);
            nm.notify(notifyID,notify);

            // Vibrate the mobile phone
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(2000);
        }

    }
```

Comment: In my project,alarm notification is getting displayed after setting an alarm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to make it work using getService instead of getBroadcast and therefore using a service instead.